# Reference ENUM by index

Tags: powershell, enums

I need to implement a lookup table scenario. I *COULD* do it with a hash table. So

```
$fruit = @{
    0 = 'Apple'
    1 = 'Pear'
    2 = 'Kiwi'
}

$fruit[1]
```

But it feels to me like an ENUM is the right native data type. however, while I can get the index of a specific enum name, I can't seem to get the name by referencing the value/index. This DOESN'T work.

```
Enum Fruit {
    Apple
    Pear
    Kiwi
}

[fruit]::1
```

Am I just completely not understanding ENUMs? Because it seems to me that looking up the index with `[fruit]::'Pear'.value__` is the opposite of what I would want to do.

For context, I want to have an ENUM that provides the corresponding strings for the integer I get back from

```
(Get-WmiObject -class:Win32_ComputerSystem -computerName:. -nameSpace:'root\CIMV2').PCSystemType
```

And ultimately I want to localize those ENUMs in a PSD1 file, so my French users get 'Portable' when PCSystemType is 2, while English speaking users would get 'Mobile'. Note, I am not actually sure that 'Portable" is correct. I need to get a friend to do the localization, but you get the point.

Anyway, is there a direct route, given the index, to get to the name? Or is the only option to coerce the enum to an array or hash table, at which point there is no reason to use an enum?

EDIT: @andy-arismendi answered the :: question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255387/how-do-i-reference-a-user-with-a-space-in-their-name). It's calling a static method of the [fruit] type, which isn't what we want. And since it's a .NET type I guess is also needs to .NET way to reference an index, which doesn't need use [#] like PowerShell? More to learn! ;)

Comment: I guess you can do this [fruit]::GetValues([fruit])[0].

Comment: `0..2|%{[fruit]($_)}` or `[enum]::getvalues([type]'Fruit')|%{'{0}:{1}' -f $_.value__,$_}`

Comment: Ah @Edijs Perkums, that's coercing, but super succinctly. It seems odd to me that [fruit]::[1] or [fruit]::1 doesn't work, but that's just how much I still have to learn. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the enum as `[fruit]1` will work in your case.

Comment: Oh, SNAP! That's the kind of thing I thought should be possible, but I was obviously barking up the wrong tree to do it. Thanks @Richard Siddaway!
Now to do some research to better understand what that double colon means. ;)

Comment: The double colon is usually used to access a static method or property. A static method/property can be accessed without creating an instance of the class